# How to tell NetBeans where gnutls is on my system?

Tags: c, macos, netbeans, configuration, gnutls

I tried to build a C/C++ project with NetBeans on my macOS Sierra, and got the following error message:

```
The following required libraries were not found:
     gnutls
Maybe some development libraries/packages are missing?
```

I do have `gnutls` installed. How can I tell NetBeans where to look for it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link to `gnutils` inside `/usr/local/bin`, e.g.

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gnutls/3.5.14/bin /usr/local/bin/gnutls
```